# ContiguousArrayStorage does not implement methodSignatureForSelector

Tags: ios, swift, contiguous

I get this warning:

```
*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x3560018 of class '_TtCSs23_ContiguousArrayStorage0000000017DB45E4' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
```

Followed by an error

```
[SwiftObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
```

On line 2 of the following code:

```
let vcs = [feedTab, channelsTab, signinTab, historyTab, moreTab]
tabBarController.setViewControllers(vcs, animated: true)
```

Where each of the tabs is an instance of UINavigationController. This only happens on my device, not on the simulator. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like it's having trouble mapping the `vcs` array to an Objective-C array. Try declaring it explicitly as an `NSArray` and see if you have better luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was being caused by one of the dynamically linked libraries for Google Analytics. I had unlinked them and disabled GA, but the error didn't go away until I did a clean before rebuild.

Comment: Just want to add that in my case I'm not using any other library and still get this error. The API that's trigger this for me is the UIPageViewController. Clean and rebuild fixes it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where it was caused by not inheriting NSObject.
I added an observer to my custom class, which wasn't inheriting NSObject, resulting in:

```
… does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: — trouble ahead
```

Just for those who enter this Q&A with this problem.